# Augment output of sql query with another query

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

I have two tables, I want to augment the output of a query on the first table with
a value from another query on the second table.

I can get the value that I want from the second table using the second query below.
This query can return multiple rows.

```
select ip_country from table2
where 
account_id = 'customer1' and
created_on >= to_timestamp('15-NOV-2013','dd-MON-yyyy')
order by created_on desc;
```

Output:

`us
(null)
us
(null)`

I'm interested in only the latest row, so I use a query like this

```
select ip_country from (select ip_country from table2 
where 
account_id = 'customer1' and
created_on >= to_timestamp('15-NOV-2013','dd-MON-yyyy')
order by created_on desc) where rownum = 1;
```

Output:
`us`

The query that I want to augment this into is this:

```
select
txnid, account_id, result
from table1     
where  
table1.txnid = 101
```

Output:
`101, customer1, PASS`

I want to write a query like

```
select
txnid, account_id, result, ip_country = (select ip_country from (select ip_country from table2 
where 
account_id = 'customer1' and
created_on >= to_timestamp('15-NOV-2013','dd-MON-yyyy')
order by created_on desc) where rownum = 1;)
from table1, table2     
where  
table1.txnid = 101;
```

This of course is syntactically wrong but hopefully this conveys the meaning.
My question is how would I write this query.

Desired Output:
`101, customer1, PASS, us`

I tried to use a join without any luck. I have omitted some of the other columns that aren't relevant to the query here. I'm working on an Oracle DB. Please feel free to change the title to something more suitable, I didn't quite know how to express this better.

Comment: Could you just provide some sample data and desired results?  I for one find it hard to follow the logic of the queries.

Comment: Sure, I'll add the sample data for the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
select txnid, account_id, result,
       (select max(ip_country) keep (dense_rank first order by created_on desc)
        from table2
        where account_id = 'customer1' and
              created_on >= to_timestamp('15-NOV-2013','dd-MON-yyyy')
       ) as ip_country
from table1 
where table1.txnid = 101;
```

However, I think you have two simple problems with your query.  First you have a semicolon in the subquery and second you have an unnecessary join in the outer query.  The above eliminates one layer of subquery, by using Oracles `keep`/`first` functionality.

Comment: I am getting a syntax error with this query, it says that FROM keyword not found where expected. In the condition `where account_id = 'customer1'` the value customer1 comes from table 1.

Comment: @nikhil You should remove `ip_country = ` part (put `ip_country` after the subquery to alias the column). And in the inner query replace `'customer1'` with `table1.account_id`.

Comment: Thanks @YaroslavShabalin. This works perfectly.
Thanks so much Gordon, I had never heard of keep/first or dense rank before this.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a need for the same account_id:

```
select t1.txnid, t1.account_id, t1.result, t2max.ip_country
from table1 t1, 
(select t2.ip_country, t2.account_id from table2 t2
 where t2.account_id = 'customer1' and 
 t2.created_on >= to_timestamp('15-NOV-2013','dd-MON-yyyy')
 order by t2.created_on desc limit 1) t2max 
where t2max.account_id = t1.account_id
group by t1.txnid, t1.account_id, t1.result;
```

or it is not the same account_id in table1 and table2:

```
select t1.txnid, t1.account_id, t1.result, t2max.ip_country
from table1 t1, 
(select t2.ip_country from table2 t2
 where t2.account_id = 'customer1' and 
 t2.created_on >= to_timestamp('15-NOV-2013','dd-MON-yyyy')
 order by t2.created_on desc limit 1) t2max 
group by t1.txnid, t1.account_id, t1.result;
```